# Loop through array of objects that have different structures and send POST requests in sequential order

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, fetch-api, es6-promise

I have an array that can store 3 different types of objects, I need to loop through the array, create the formatted payload, then send a POST request for every object in the array in sequential order, (i.e. only send the second POST request after the first is resolved. then send third after the second is resolved).

Problem is, there are 3 different types of objects i need to check for (command, CMAction, notification), and they are not resolving in the same order because the type check in my if statements.

Each of the 3 types needs to get sent to a different function to structure the correct payload and send the POST request:

```
const {
    commands: copiedCommands,
    client_management_actions: copiedCMActions,
    notifications: copiedNotifications,
  } = copiedResponseSet;

 //new array with all actions, notifications & commands
  const copiedActionsArray = [...copiedCommands, ...copiedCMActions, ...copiedNotifications];
  const sortedCopiedActionsArray = copiedActionsArray.sort((a, b) => a.created_at.localeCompare(b.created_at));

  for (let i = 0; i < sortedCopiedActionsArray.length; i++) {
    if ("properties" in sortedCopiedActionsArray[i]) {
      const command = await createCommandsPayload(sortedCopiedActionsArray[i], newResponseSetID);
    }

    if ("action_type" in sortedCopiedActionsArray[i]) {
      const CMAction = await createCMActionsPayload(sortedCopiedActionsArray[i], newResponseSetID);
    }

    if ("notifiable_type" in sortedCopiedActionsArray[i]) {
      const notification = await createNotificationsPayload(sortedCopiedActionsArray[i], newResponseSetID);       
    }
  }
```

function that creates the commands payload and sends the POST request

```
const createCommandsPayload = async (copiedCommand, newResponseSetID) => {
  const commandPayload = createInitialCommands(copiedCommand);
  const commandData = await commandPOSTFetch(commandPayload, newResponseSetID);

  return commandData;
};

const commandPOSTFetch = async (command, newResponseSetID) => {
  const res = await fetch(
    `https://${hostname}/api/v2/apps/${appID}/interactions/${interactionID}/response_sets/${newResponseSetID}/commands.json`,
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(command),
    }
  );
  const data = await res.json();
  return data;
};
```

Function that creates the CMAction payload and sends the POST request

```
const createCMActionsPayload = async (copiedCMAction, newResponseSetID) => {
  const actionPayload = createInitialActions(copiedCMAction);
  const actionData = await actionsPOSTFetch(actionPayload, newResponseSetID);
  return actionData;
};

const actionsPOSTFetch = async (action, newResponseSetID) => {
  const res = await fetch(`https://${hostname}/api/v2/apps/${appID}/interactions/${interactionID}/response_sets/${newResponseSetID}/client_management_actions.json`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(action),
  });
  const data = await res.json();
  return data;
};
```

function that creates the notifications payload and sends the POST request:

```
const createNotificationsPayload = async (copiedNotification, newResponseSetID) => {
  const notificationsPayload = createInitialNotifications(copiedNotification);
  const data = await notificationsPOSTFetch(notificationsPayload, newResponseSetID);
  return data;
};

const notificationsPOSTFetch = async (notification, newResponseSetID) => {
  const res = await fetch(`https://${hostname}/api/v2/apps/${appID}/interactions/${interactionID}/response_sets/${newResponseSetID}/notifications.json`,
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(notification),
    }
  );
  const data = await res.json();
  return data;
};
```

For example, if I run the loop on an array that has object types sorted in this particular order:

```
1. command object type
2. CMAction object type
3. command object type
4. notification object type
5. CMAction object type
6. command object type
```

the promises do not get resolved in that same order, instead they the list will be

```
1. command object type
2. command object type
3. command object type
4. CMAction object type
5. CMAction object type
6. notification object type
```

**Reading in Sequence of the Array:** 

How can I make sure, **regardless of the object type**, that the next POST request isn't send until the previous iteration has been resolved?

Comment: do your "createXyzPayload" functions do the POST also or just return the payload?  If they do the post we'd need to see that code to make sure the promise it returns is actually waiting on the post to complete.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yes, the functions create the payload and make the POST

Comment: then can you edit your question to include the source code of one of those functions?  I suspect that the promise it returns isn't quite right.  It can be a simplified version of the code as long as it shows how the post is made and what the return value is.

Comment: The problem is not in the code you have shared. Please add actual (sample) initialisation of the array `sortedCopiedActionsArray`, add the definition of the function  `createNotificationsPayload`. You can skip irrelevant code, but make sure that what remains still has the problem.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning functions with the POST requests added

Comment: @trincot Gotcha, more code added for context.

Comment: Does your actual code use a for-loop as you show, or might you be using array.forEach or something like that? I know there are problems trying to use await in that kind of loop.

Comment: how do you know the order it processed them? Did you do a console.log somewhere?  It's not in the sample code you gave

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yes, an actual for-loop, not forEach. I think is has something to do with the if-checks. through each iteration, if the object types are different, then it can fire off a POST without waiting for the previous to finish resolving.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I know the order because after they get sent via POST, they are parsed in the DOM (in the wrong order).

Comment: not sure how you tell the order in the DOM.  Try putting a console.log after each call in the if statements and see if they're in the right order.   Your code above doesn't show what happens with the result after it's complete. You just put them in a local variable, but  if it's going in the DOM we're missing that part of the code.

Comment: the for-loop should execute them one by one. You must be doing more processing after the await finishes with the result it gives.  It may be that processing after the await that is asynchronous and not waited upon itself.  That's my guess but I'd need to see what you do with the results to be more helpful.

Comment: My guess is that the results coming back from `command` actions and smallest so get processed faster than the others, and `notification` is the largest result so gets handled slower and is last.  does that make sense?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yeah that makes sense, I tested by placing all resolves in an array, correct order. even logged after every POST, they are being sent up in the right order as well.

Comment: ok, so answer here is that the code does work - the wrong order is happening afterwards probably as a result of not serializing how the DOM is populated

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Found out there was a "created_at" key being added on the server, which timestamps the object then our platform sorts it by that timestamp in the DOM. Problem was every request was getting the same exact time stamp, hence the random order.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning gonna have to separate these requests with something like a Sequential Promise Queue, so they hit the server at different times.